# Screen, or similar, for automatically resuming a flaky ssh connection

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, session

I often have to connect to a server over ssh in an unreliable wifi environment.  On the server, I run screen, so if I get disconnected, I can reconnect and resume the screen session, and pick up where I left off, but the loss of connection is still a major time sink:  if the connection drops out while I'm on the server, the terminal window tends to freeze.  I have to kill that tab, open a new one, ssh to the server again and resume the screen session.  I've tried this with running screen on the server and screen locally.  Either way it tends to freeze when the connection drops out.

Is there any way I can have something similar to screen, or maybe screen itself, that will automatically try to reconnect and keep the session running, so I don't have to keep manually reconnecting?  Often when I lose the connection I think it's only for a very brief period - less than a second maybe.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, MATE edition.  thanks

Comment: Re "the shell window tends to freeze": That's because your local ssh doesn't know the connection is dead. Hit `<Enter>` and type `~.` to tell your side to drop the connection, and you can simply repeat the last ssh command to reconnect (e.g. with up-arrow or `!!`).

Comment: @alexis that sounds like a quicker way to reconnect, thanks!  I'd love it to happen automatically though...

Answer (score 24):

You could look at using `mosh`: https://mosh.org/

You could set up a 'jump' server with a reliable internet connection which you use `mosh` to connect to, then have `ssh` sessions to each server you manage.
The reason I suggest using a jump server is that you may not wish to install `mosh` on the servers you are managing.

Another advantage of `mosh` is that it is based on UDP rather than TCP, and your session can survive a change of IP address, for example going from WiFi to a mobile internet connection.

Just to make it clear, `mosh` is not a replacement for `screen`, but rather `ssh`. It's still a good idea to use `screen` with it, since `mosh` itself doesn't provide a way to reconnect to your session if the client dies for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, it is just the one server (most of the time) and we own it so I should be able to install Mosh.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Actually it turns out that because our server's quite old (or running an old Ubuntu i should say) it's too difficult to install.  :(

Comment: @MaxWilliams how old is it? Even LTS 12.4 has gone out of support. And why don't just try compiling it yourself

Comment: As I read the mosh docs, you need mosh-server on each host you intend to remotely manage.  Still, definitely interesting.

Comment: Connecting to a tmux terminal over mosh is the most stable solution for me.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I've not investigated it directly but according to our lead tech guy it's a "yak shaving job", ie has lots of dependencies, each with their own hurdles.  I would need to compile it myself - that's ok, but the other stuff sounds like it might be too much hassle.

Comment: I forget what the reason was, but I remember Mosh was missing some features that made it a dealbreaker...

Answer (score 3):

I have been using [`tmux`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) for a few years now and in my experience, it reconnects automatically. At least when the connection only fails for a relatively brief time. Note that I actually use [`byobu`](https://byobu.org/) with tmux as the backend. I don't know if this robustness is a feature of `tmux` or `byobu` or even of the combination of the two, but I suggest you give both a try.

I connect from my local Arch install to various remote Ubuntu servers through a VPN. I tested it just now by unplugging my network cable while I was connected to the remote. The session hung, but as soon as my cable was plugged in again, it resumed seamlessly.

However, when I tested by restarting my router, the connection did not return. I assume it has something to do with how long the network was down, but it does seem to reconnect if it's only down a few seconds.

In case it's relevant, I do all this using [`terminator`](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) as my terminal emulator.

All three are available in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux terminator byobu
```

However, I am not at all sure that either `tmux` or `byobu` are better at handling ssh disconnections. I only know that in my experience, they often come back from short connection losses. That may be down to other aspects of my configuration though.

Comment: When you restarted your router you may have been given a different public IP address, which will have broken the `tcp` connection. From my experience `ssh` can be very resilient to intermittent network drop outs, I don't think this has anything to do with the fact you're using `tmux` inside the `ssh` window.

Comment: I was going to say the same: even with plain SSH, you can deal with a short disconnection, as long as the TCP connection doesn't die. Which it might, if your interface gets shutdown, or some overzealous router kills it (NAT routers might forget the NAT state on reboot, and break existing connections), or `ClientAlive`/`ServerAlive` triggers, or... I've no idea what `byobu` does, though.

Comment: Yes, but the OP seems to be experiencing freezing on any connection failure, while I don't. But yes, you're right, I also see this with simple ssh and no tmux. Nevertheless, maybe screen can't deal with it?

Comment: tmux kind of sounds like `screen`, but with better management of lost connections.  Is it the case that I leave a tmux session on the server, then start a tmux session locally, and then connect to the server tmux from inside it, then they keep their connection (barring major issues)?

Comment: And byobu is like the gnome terminal but built on tmux, is that right?

Comment: @MaxWilliams `tmux` is basically a more modern alternative to `screen`, yes. When I first started to work as I do now and needed this sort of thing, my cursory reading suggested that `tmux` is the better choice these days. I am also not 100% sure it has better management of lost connections, all I know is that it does recover from brief outages in my experience. Whether that's down to `tmux` or something else, I don't know. But it seems worth trying :). Byobu is basically a frontend to screen/tmux, not a GUI terminal emulator. It is exceedingly useful though: http://byobu.org/

Comment: tmux does not do anything about connection interruptions. It works with the terminal device provided by ssh. It all stands and falls with the ssh connection.

Answer (score 3):

Use ssh's `ServerAlive` options to detect when the connection has failed.

> `ServerAliveCountMax`
>    Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which may be sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from the
>    server.  If this threshold is reached while server alive messages are being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server,
>    terminating the session.  It is important to note that the use of server alive messages is very different from
>    TCPKeepAlive (below).  The server alive messages are sent through the encrypted channel and therefore will not be spoofable.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by TCPKeepAlive is spoofable.  The server alive mechanism is valuable when the
>    client or server depend on knowing when a connection has become inactive.
>
> The default value is 3.  If, for example, ServerAliveInterval (see below) is set to 15 and ServerAliveCountMax is left at
>    the default, if the server becomes unresponsive, ssh will disconnect after approximately 45 seconds.
>
> `ServerAliveInterval`
>            Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message
>            through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages
>            will not be sent to the server.

So if you set `ServerAliveInterval` to 5, `ssh` will automatically disconnect if the network flakes out for 15 seconds.

Comment: To break an SSH session by force, I press `~.` (or first Enter, then `~.`) consisting of: the escape character `~` and the command to break the session `.`

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev That assumes you can tell that the connection is hung. Using SSH's keepalive will detect the failure automatically.

Comment: That sounds really useful, thanks, I'll definitely try that next time i'm in the "flaky zone".

Comment: @Barmar Yes, true. I've also thought about the problem of determining whether the connection is really hung, or me pressing something can accidentally send these keys to the remote side... And I don't know a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

In similar conditions, I tend to use `eshell` with TRAMP (over ssh) inside Emacs. TRAMP takes care of reconnecting when necessary without causing much trouble for me giving the wanted commands for the remote shell.

However, eshell is not good as a terminal, i.e., for running commands that do something special with the terminal, or that run for a significant period of time continuously (incrementally) printing something out.

Basically, it's quite simple to start using it in Emacs with TRAMP:

```
M-x eshell
cd /user@host:
```

Answer (score 1):

## Disclaimer

If your SSH connection is not surviving brief network outages, then there's *something else* going on that's not letting `ssh` and TCP do their normal thing.

See below for details. Anyway:

## The Quickest-and-Dirtiest No-Dependencies Solution

Create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -

# Tune these numbers depending on how aggressively
# you want your SSH session to get reconnected.
timeout_options='-o ServerAliveInterval=4 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2'

# 255 is the status OpenSSH uses to signal SSH errors, which
# means we want to connect. All other exit statuses suggest
# an intentional exit.
status=255

# Keep opening the SSH connection and immediately dropping into
# `screen` until an intentional exit happens.
while [ "$status" = 255 ]
do
    ssh $timeout_options -t "$@" screen -dR
    status=$?
    # You can add a `sleep` command here or a counter or whatever
    # you might need as far as rate/retry limiting.
done
exit "$status"
```

This will just run a stupid-simple loop that keeps trying to connect with `ssh` and attach to `screen`. Pass the host or whatever else you'd normally pass to your `ssh` invocation as command-line arguments.

The reconnect is just based on whether SSH reports an error with the connection, which means it has no intelligence for detecting non-SSH errors like "you literally don't have WiFI turned on" or whatever, but that probably doesn't matter for you.

I'm assuming you have `ssh-agent` or a no-passphrase SSH key that will allow reconnects to just work without additional input from you.

There's going to be a tiny race condition where if you hit `^C` during just the right human-imperceptible fraction of a second during a reconnect you could end up killing the script instead of passing the `^C` through to the client terminal, so if you suspect a connection hang don't mash `^C` too zealously.

## Simplest Additional Software Solution

You can try the program [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), which should be available in your Ubuntu package repository.

If you need to build from source or audit it, it's a single C program that compiles without any additional libraries as dependencies, seems to have more intelligence about checking connection liveliness than my hack above, *and* it also ships with a convenient `rscreen` script command which auto-attaches to `screen`.

## Details

### How `ssh` normally recovers

Just to verify, because I don't like saying things without checking myself, I ran a little test before answering:

I got on my WiFi with a Linux device, made an SSH connection to another device on my LAN, verified I had a working `ssh` connection to the other end (could run commands, etc), then on the client *disconnected the WiFi* (causing the interface to be de-configured: no more IP addresses), typed a bunch more characters into the ssh session (no response, of course), and then reconnected to my WiFi - the reconnection actually failed at least once due to bad signal and other factors, then finally reconnected: I waited about five seconds for the `ssh` session to recover, nothing happened so I hit one more key, and the `ssh` session immediately came alive again, with all the keys that I had typed during the disconnect appearing on the command line.

See, `ssh` just writes/reads into the TCP network socket until the OS tells it something went wrong, and TCP is actually *very* tolerant of prolonged connection drops.

Left to its own devices with default kernel settings the TCP stack in Linux will happily tolerate the connection going completely silent for many minutes before declaring the connection dead and reporting an error to `ssh` - by the time it finally gives up we're talking in the ballpark of ~30 minutes, or at least certainly long enough to outlast connection hiccups lasting a second or a minute.

Underneath the covers, the Linux TCP stack gradually retries messages with longer and longer delays, though, which means that by the time your connection does come back, you might be looking at additional lag before your `ssh` session seems to come "alive" again.

### Why this sometimes breaks

Often something is actively causing the connection to close after some *significantly shorter* period of inactivity than the amount that the TCP stack will tolerate, and then failing to report that connection state to your `ssh` client.

Likely candidates include:

1. Firewalls or NAT'ing routers, which have to use memory to remember each live TCP connection - as an optimization and some mitigation against DOS attacks, they will sometimes just *forget* your connection, and then *silently ignore* consequent packets for it, because packets in the middle of a connect when you don't remember the connection existing look invalid.
2. Better-behaved firewalls/routers will inject a TCP RST packet, which typically manifests as a `connection reset by peer` error message, but the reset packet is a fire-and-forget, so if the connection to your client is still having issues at that moment and drops the reset packet too, your client will think the connection is still alive.
3. The server *itself* might have a firewall policy to silently drop unexpected packets, which would break the client's connection resumption attempts whenever the server thinks the connection closed but the client doesn't: your client keeps trying to continue the connection, but the server is just ignoring it because there's no live connection to which these packets belong in the server's firewall state.

   Since you're running Linux, carefully check your server's `iptables`/`ip6tables` (or `nft` if you're using the new stuff) for exactly what you're allowing vs. dropping. It's very common to allow *new*/*established*/*related* packets on the TCP SSH port, but *not* "invalid" ones - if you're dropping silently everything that isn't allowed, this common setup could cause these kinds of freezes after brief connection issues.
4. Your SSH server itself might be configured to close the connection after a period of inactivity, using one of OpenSSH options for TCP or SSH client keepalive packets. By itself this won't cause indefinite hangs, but it can put you in one of the states described above.
5. It's possible you're just not giving it enough time to "unhang" on its own after you get into the state where your `ssh` session hangs up.